# Can someone explain the scala code below?

Tags: scala

```
scala> def lift3[A,B,C,D] (
     | f: Function3[A,B,C,D]): Function3[Option[A], Option[B], Option[C], Option
[D]] = {
     | (oa: Option[A], ob:Option[B], oc: Option[C]) =>
     | for(a <- oa; b <- ob; c <- oc) yield f(a,b,c)
     | }
lift3: [A, B, C, D](f: (A, B, C) => D)(Option[A], Option[B], Option[C]) => Option[D]
```

In particular, the following line:

```
def lift3[A,B,C,D] (
          f: Function3[A,B,C,D]): Function3[Option[A], Option[B], Option[C], Option
    [D]]
```

This is taken from the book Scala In Depth by Joshua D Suereth (Listing 2.1, chapter 2). I'm not sure what purpose the additional `Option[D]` serves. In the body of the function, the code only maps to the first three parameters to the output type `D`. When then, `D` is declared in the input parameter list? Am I missing something?

With my limited understanding, I would read the function declaration as a function that takes a function as a parameter (which in turn takes 4 parameters) and returns a function that takes 4 parameters. Also, why is there no mention of the return type?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> With my limited understanding, I would read the function declaration as a function that takes a function as a parameter (which in turn takes 4 parameters) and returns a function that takes 4 parameters. Also, why is there no mention of the return type?

`Function3[A,B,C,D]` is a function with *3* parameters (of types `A`, `B` and `C`) and `D` is the return type (it can also be written as `(A, B, C) => D`; this is exactly the same type). So in `Function3[Option[A], Option[B], Option[C], Option[D]]`, `Option[D]` is the return type, not a parameter type.

Comment: Thanks a million! Can you perhaps point to some documentation regarding the convention that the last parameter is the return type?

Answer (score 2):

A `function3` takes 3 parameters. The `D` is the return type of the function. What the code does, is take a function with 3 arguments and return a function with 3 arguments, where each argument and its return type is "lifted" to an `Option`.

You can check out the API docs for `Function3`  [here.](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.Function3)
And an explanation for the `R` generic type can be found in the docs for [Function2](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.Function2)